# Conversion of arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, type-conversion

Assume we have an array of integers, say int[] x={0,1,2,3};

Can I convert x into an array of type String?
Can I upcast x into an array of doubles?
By the above conversions, I mean converting all entries of the array collectively, not individually.

How do generally conversions work for arrays in java? Do I have to convert each entry of the original array and assign it to the corresponding entry of the target array?

Comment: you need to do programatically - the is no auto-conversion

Comment: **Do I have to convert each entry of the original array and assign it to the corresponding entry of the target array?** Obviously

Comment: @MehrajMalik - why *Obviously* ? Some people do not know this stuff

Comment: In this scenario you can use a lambda function having `s -> Integer.parseInt(s)` . And yes there have to be a target array.

Comment: Despite all the coded loops and streams below, don't forget about `Arrays.toString()`.  Generally in Java we convert things to string by using the built-in API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In java8 you can do:

```
    int[] x = {0,1,2,3};
    // int to double
    double[] doublesArray = Arrays.stream(x).asDoubleStream().toArray();
    //int to string
    String[] stringArray = Arrays.stream(x).mapToObj(String::valueOf).toArray(String[]::new);
    // string to double
    double[] doublesArrayFromString = Arrays.stream(stringArray).mapToDouble(Double::valueOf).toArray();

    Arrays.stream(doublesArray).forEach(System.out::println);
    Arrays.stream(stringArray).forEach(System.out::println);
    Arrays.stream(doublesArrayFromString).forEach(System.out::println);
```

[Here](https://ideone.com/TFZZHf)'s running code.

Answer (score 6):

With Java 8 it is possible in one line you can do this

```
int[] x = {0,1,2,3};
double[] doubles = Arrays.stream(x).asDoubleStream().toArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

To convert int into string array you can use `Stream`

```
String[] strinArray=  Arrays.Stream(nums).mapToObj(String::valueOf).toArray(String[]::new); //where nums is int array
```

another way is

```
String[] strinArray = Arrays.toString(nums).replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "").split("\\s*,\\s*");
```

To convert int into double you can use below snippet

```
double[] doubles = Arrays.stream(nums).asDoubleStream().toArray();
```

Note : Above code will work in java 8 only

Answer (score 2):

You can possibly do casting from int , double , float etc. to String using one liner code as below:

```
int[] x={0,1,2,3};
String stringArray=Arrays.toString(x);
```

But to cast from int to double you would need to iterate and cast it individually in loop.

With java8, it is possible using streams

```
long[] longArray = Arrays.stream(x).mapToLong(i -> i).toArray();
double[] doubleArray = Arrays.stream(x).mapToDouble(i -> i).toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also convert an int array to String array without using stream methods or if you are using lower version of java.

import java.util.Arrays;

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] x = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
        String[] stringArray = Arrays.toString(x).split("[\\[\\]]")[1].split(", ");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stringArray));
    }

}
```